# Processing response of external web service with Apache Camel

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm considering two small Spring Boot applications:

- **Applcation 1**: A small web service running on http://localhost:8081, implementing a simple Spring Controller responding to GET requests on /camel. The service just returns "Hello world" when visiting http://localhost:8081/camel.
- **Application 2**: A small application that should execute a GET request to Application 1 and print out the response to the console (in this case "Hello world").

Using Springs `RestTemplate`, I can easily implement this GET request in Application 2:

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
String response = template.getForBody("http://localhost:8081/camel", String.class);
System.out.println(response);
```

My goal now is to use Apache Camel instead of Spring's `RestTemplate`. 
I've tried defining the following RouteBuilder:

```
public class MyRoutes extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception() {
        from("jetty:http://localhost:8081/camel").to("direct:processRest");

        from("direct:processRest").process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the application however, I receive the following error:

```
org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

Either Spring Boot or Apache Camel automatically tries to launch a Jetty Server on port 8081, but the other web service (Application 1) is already running on this port.

Does anybody know how to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing comes from the fact that you're using Camel's Jetty component as a consumer, which brings up an embedded Jetty server and binds it to port 8081, thus conflicting with your Spring Boot app. To send HTTP requests, you should use Jetty component as a producer, i.e change your route definition to be something like

`from("scheduler:camelTest?delay=1000").to("jetty:http://localhost:8081/camel").to("direct:processRest");`

Comment: This I already understood :)
But I don't understand how I can let jetty run on port 8282 but use port 8281 in the route specification. Whatever I try, Jetty always launches on the port that is used in the route....

Comment: Well, since you're using from() in your Application 2's route declaration you're bringing up an embedded Jetty and listening to requests on /camel path

Comment: Oh, **now** I understand - sorry, I seem to have misunderstood your question. I'll update my answer right away.